# Unable to read specific JSON keys in my lambda function

Tags: node.js, json, post, aws-lambda

Having this undefined issue in my node lambda function here is the code

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
console.log('top')
console.log(event.body)
console.log(event.body.value)
console.log('bottom')

return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(event)
} }
```

And here is a cloud watch screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Im new to lambda and post requests so any help as to the value key is much appreciated

Comment: what happens if you try `event.body.'value'` instead?

Comment: blurfus it errors out with the following {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected string",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected string",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:200:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` property of a lambda handler's `event` parameter is in string format by default. If you use `typeof` to view the data type of the body, you'll get a return value of string:

```js
console.log(typeof event.body);  // logs 'string'
```

To access the `body` property using object syntax, you have to parse it first using `JSON.parse` method:

```js
let body = JSON.parse(event.body);
```

to avoid unexpected surprise from naughty consumers, you can use this function which I personally use on my projects:

```js
/**
   * @function getJsonBody
   * @description Method used for retrieving the JSON body of HTTP requests.
   * @param {object} event Lambda event parameter.
   * @returns {object} JSON body of request payload.
   */
  getJsonBody(event) {
    if (event && event.body !== null && event.body !== undefined) {
      try {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body);

        return body;
      } catch (err) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```